# why background image offset ~25% when "background-attachment: local"?

Tags: html, background, local, fixed

Can someone please help me understand why this CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
      background: url(images/img.diary.1280.jpg) no-repeat center center local; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    body {
      font-family: 'alpha geometrique', fantasy, cursive, sans-serif;
      background: none;
    }...
```

would make the background image "move up" by ~25% so that only the bottom ~75% of the picture is shown, compared to this alternate "background:" line?

```
background: url(images/img.diary.1280.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

which shows 100% of the picture fitting within the viewport (which is what I desire)?

I have also tried "scroll" but that has the same effect as "local". The reason I don't want to use fixed is that when I scroll the window, the elements (bootstrap 4) scroll but the background image does not making it look like the elements are sliding on top. **I prefer the elements & the image scroll together, which is the real objective I'm trying to achieve**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the `background-size: cover` and the aspect ratio of the image. Cover will increase the size of the image until it covers both width and height so if the image is portrait and the window is landscape it will increase the size of the image(maintaining aspect) until it is as wide as the window which makes it taller than the window, and since you have it centered vertically the top and bottom will not be visible. Try this:

```
  html {
    background: url(images/img.diary.1280.jpg) no-repeat center center local; 
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
  }
```

Contain is like best-fit, it will increase (or decrease) the size of the image to the largest size that will fit inside the window.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, Arleigh. With "contain", the image does not stretch (as you pointed out) to fill the viewport. But you did point me in the right direction. What I needed is to change `background-position: center center` to `background-position: center top` while keeping `background-attachment: local`. Now I have both the behaviour I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos Arleigh Hix for pointing me in the right direction.

What I needed is to change `background-position: center center` to `background-position: center top` while keeping `background-attachment: local`. Now I have both the behaviour I want.

Comment: Kudos are great but, if I helped you understand why this CSS would make the background image "move up", as you asked, could you please _accept_ my answer, Thanks.